# Mapping Input with different codecs

Tags: ffmpeg

is it possible to encode to two different codecs with one input? I tried also tee muxer with no luck. Thanks.

> -y -timeout 10000000 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://rtsp.stream/pattern -map 0:v -vf "transpose=1" -c:v bmp -f image2pipe - -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -an -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `split` filter and use `-map` twice.

In case the input has both video and audio streams, we may use `split` for the video and `asplit` for the audio, and we have to map both the video and the audio.

We can't use `tee` muxer for encoding with two different codecs - `tee` muxer splits a stream which is already encoded (may split to two different containers/formats).

---

Example with synthetic video:

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -filter_complex "split[v0][v1]" -vcodec bmp -f image2 -map "[v0]" frame%05d.bmp -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -map "[v1]" test_output.mp4`

- `-filter_complex "split[v0][v1]"` splits the input video stream into two streams with temporary names `[v0]` and `[v1]`.
- `-map "[v0]" frame%05d.bmp` maps `[v0]` to `frame%05d.bmp` output (`[v0]` codec and format defined by `-vcodec bmp -f image2`).
- `-map "[v1]" test_output.mp4` maps `[v1]` to `test_output.mp4` output (`[v1]` codec and format defined by `-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4`).

---

Example with your command (not tested):

`ffmpeg -y -an -timeout 10000000 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://rtsp.stream/pattern -filter_complex "transpose=1,split[v0][v1]" -c:v bmp -f image2pipe -map "[v0]" - -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -f flv -map "[v1]" rtmp://127.0.0.1/live`

Comment: Thank you very much!! Split did the trick and you example works flawlessly !